# 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found webview_flutter-1.0.7

Tags: flutter

Please help me! I don't know what is that problem but I think is since I updated to the latest version of flutter.
I tried with , flutter clean, rm podfile, and more !! but I can't fix that ,is problem from flutter?
I have two days trying to repair it, but I have not been successful.

*I update all my pods, I did all!, but I can't do that work.. (flutter doctor its ok)
my flutter version is
**I tried that in channel stable too, but not worked.

```
Flutter 1.26.0-2.0.pre.157 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4b83be6c23 (9 hours ago) • 2020-12-30 02:09:03 -0500
Engine • revision 0e5a25d779
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-179.0.dev)

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/victormanuellagunas/Documents/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
    /Users/victormanuellagunas/Documents/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-1.0.7/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Try "flutter clean", then 'flutter channel stable" (or dev). if that doesn't work, then you should try "webview_flutter-1.0.6"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same Problem and solved it with these Steps:

1. go to this Directory `/Users/victormanuellagunas/Documents/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org`
2. Delete the `webview_flutter-1.0.7` Folder
3. Then run following command in project folder.

   `flutter pub get`

If this is not working the try to use a lower Version for example 1.0.6

Comment: Thank you mir Rahed, but I can to see two times the same dependence , I deleted that , but the project have more and more same problems,it's very strange because this didn't happen before

Comment: @VictorLagunas you are welcome, that I answered you the Question. Mir only suggested edit that i approved.

Did you tried to a lower Version?

Comment: thank you a lot all guys, I had a solution for that, I don't know why happened that, but I have the same bug in all my projects... so I need delete the iOS folder (create a backup of iOS/Runner) after that , write 'flutter create . '.